# UIStoryboard+UITabBarController+Separate storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

There's a main `UIStoryboard` with a `UITabBarController` that has 5 items each of which is big enough to be represented by its own storyboard instance. I would like to divide all 5 into different storyboards. In other words, when `TabBarItem1` is selected, I would like to load its respective `UIViewController` from a different storyboard, is it possible to achieve this? I'm thinking about creating the `UITabBarController` programmatically for this, would that be the most graceful solution?

EDIT --

```
  NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

  MyViewController1 *myController1 = [[StoryboardManager myStoryboard1] instantiateInitialViewController];
  myController1.title = @"Title";
  [viewControllers addObject:myController1];

  MyViewController2 *myController2 = [[StoryboardManager myStoryboard2] instantiateInitialViewController];
  myController2.title = @"Title";
  [viewControllers addObject:myController2];
  // ...etc
  self.viewControllers = viewControllers; // self - subclass of a UITabBarController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in code, by getting an instance of the other storyboards, instantiating their initial view controller, and finally, adding those to the tab bar controllers viewControllers array.

Comment: @Eugene can you edit your question with the code of how you did it?

Comment: @Eugene Thanks! it seems to me that StoryboardManager is actually a class category on UIStoryBoard?

Comment: That's a subclass of an `NSObject` that I use to manage my multiple storyboards properly. You can initiate them the usual way with `storyboardWithName:`

Answer (score 0):

If you work with iOS9, it's possible to select all view controllers in one tab of UITabbarController, select Editor -> Refactor to Storyboard in XCode, and create a new Storyboard. XCode will do everything else automatically. Unfortunately, it works only from iOS 9.